# Speed up and optimize scikit-learn on Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I run Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud VM on Ubuntu 16.04. The VM has 8 CPUs and 32 GB memory (and can be easily increased).
When i run some of my ML scripts i can see that VM is not loaded fully. 
I noticed that adding `n_jobs = 16` for `GridSearchCV` helps: VM machine is 100% loaded and calculations are quicker.

There are two questions:

- What are the other parameters of scikit learn functions i should look for to make sure im using full power of the VM? For example with fit, transform, predict methods.
- Are there any other parameters in VM (apart from CPU and memory) that i should change in order to speed up ML tasks?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of sklearn's parallelization, everything is controlled by `n_jobs` (and a lot is hidden by the underlying BLAS/LAPACK build; see below!).

Now there are two different levels in your example:

- A: Parallelization on the algorithm-level as supported for *some* methods

  - e.g. [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
  - activated on algorithm-level: e.g. `clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=10)`
  - granularity and effect is hard to read out the docs: for RandomForest's you can gain near-linear speedup if `n_jobs <= n_estimators` (because each single estimator can be touched independent on others!)
- B: Parallelization on some outer GridSearchCV

  - activated on GridSearch-level: e.g. `clf = GridSearchCV(clf_, parameters, n_jobs=10)`
  - this achieves near-linear speedups for `n_grid_search_trials >= n_jobs`

If **A** is used (again: not supported for everything), it's also used for it's methods like predict and transform.

Of these two candidates, B is (slightly) less granular and more the case of [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). If the condition for full speedup (see above) is fulfilled; i would only use this approach during fit. When needed, one could reset `n_jobs` of the estimator after for fitting. But it's not expected, that this will help lots.

Other (more obvious hardware things):

- SSD vs. HDD (if learning is somewhat IO-bound; hard to tell without testing)

Another **very important thing**:

- Use the fastest [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)/[LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) implementation available and make sure it's build with support for parallelization (a lot of time is spent within these routines; BLAS-example: matrix-vector multiplication; LAPACK-example: solve system of linear equations)

  - The setup / linking is done at numpy/scipy install; not sklearn

    - although i'm unsure what exactly happens with 3rd-party software like [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/), [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and co. in use (and brought by sklearn); which will use BLAS too
    - i think those libs bring their own reduced BLAS-code indicated [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/tree/master/blas) which means: we don't care
  - Usual candidates are: ATLAS, OpenBLAS, Intel's MKL (intuition: slower to faster) and so on...
  - One of the advantages of the [Anaconda-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) is the fact it's coming with [MKL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) out of the box.